# Capital letter in letters after salutation ("Liebe ...,")

Tags: capitalization, letter

My German teacher has told me that when writing a letter, in the sentence following "Dear xxx," I shouldn't use a capital letter, and that this rule also holds in English. (I'm not a native English speaker.) I'm wondering if both of her statements are true, seeing as I found this: 
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11906/should-i-capitalize-the-starting-sentence-after-a-greeting-that-ends-in-a-comma

Comment: I usually use an exclamation mark (no longer required, these days, but still allowed): there can be no doubt that you'll start your next sentence with a capital letter after that. That said, if you do use a comma, the sentence is continued, as it were: only nouns etc. will be capitalized.

Comment: @Ingmar this is actually the correct answer. Why don't you provide one?

Comment: Not sure this qualifies as an answer :-) I'll keep it a comment for the time being.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rules of English and German are different:

In **German** you use NO capital, unless the first word after adress ist a noun. See also [this](http://www.online-lernen.levrai.de/deutsch-uebungen/briefe/01_briefe_schreiben.htm) page.

> Sehr geehrter Herr Müller,
>
> ich entschuldige mich für...

In **English** you use capital. You needn’t set a comma, but you can. In American Englisch you use a colon.

> Dear Mrs Fisher,
>
> My sincere apologies for....

Comment: A related discussion about capital letters (or not) after the greetings in English, could be found here: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/195332/23212

Comment: You use a colon in American Enlgish? "Dear Mrs Fisher:" ?

Comment: @Adam I took that from https://english.stackexchange.com/a/195332

Comment: @Devon in this answer its stated that the president uses colon :D

Answer (score 5):

If you use a comma ("Liebe Anna,"), the following part has to start like the rules of the german language are providing. So if a verb is following after the comma, it has to be written without a capital letter; if a substantive is following, you have to write it capitalized.

A different case is the usage of an exclamation mark ("Liebe Anna!") - in this case, the greeting is an independent sentence and the following part has to start capitalized.

Answer (score 5):

In German, there are different rules depending on the variety.

In **Germany standard German,** the salutation is separated by a comma from the first sentence, which starts with a small letter (as if the salutation were part of the first sentence):

> Liebe Leute,
>
> in Deutschland schreibt man klein.

In **Swiss standard German,** the salutation has no punctuation mark and the first sentence starts with a capital letter (as if the salutation were a title):

> Liebe Leute
>
> In der Schweiz schreibt man gross.

Comment: Vielen Dank für diese Antwort. Ich lebe in der Schweiz!